# Pandas Getting sum of column value for next 6 months data for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
                         id               date             num
0                         1            2005-01-01           7
1                         1            2006-01-05           2
2                         2            2005-01-01           1
3                         2            2005-04-01           1
4                         3            2009-01-01           2
```

For each `id` group, I want to get the sum of `num` for next 6 months' data. For example, for `id=1`, there is no data for next 6 months so, sum will be 0. For `id=2`, there is 1 num in next  6 months, so `total=1`.

I am able to do this for each sub group but not for complete dataset. For one `sub-group` dataframe, this is what I tried:

```
 df1 = df[df['id']==1]
 
 def get_future_sum(val):
     end_date = val.date + relativedelta(months=+6)
     date_range = df1[(df1['date'] > val.date) &
                     (df1['date'] <= end_date)]
     return date_range['num'].sum()

df1['total'] = df1.apply(get_future_sum, axis=1)
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
                     id               date             total
0                         1            2005-01-01           0
1                         1            2006-01-05           0
2                         2            2005-01-01           1
3                         2            2005-04-01           0
4                         3            2009-01-01           0
```

I tried to iterate it over multiple groups using groupby and apply but it does not work because `df1` changes for each group and I am not sure how to accommodate that.

Is there a shorter way to iterate it over all the groups without using for loop for each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Original question: *Is there a shorter way to iterate it over all the groups?*

  - Use `groupby` to collect the dataframe groups by `id`
- *I tried to iterate it over multiple groups using `groupby` and `apply` but it does not work because `df1` changes for each group and I am not sure how to accommodate that.*

  - It works when implemented correctly by updating the grouped dataframe sent to the function
- *Is there a shorter way to iterate it over all the groups without using for loop for each group?*

  - Probably not, because the function requires the dataframe for each group to determine `date_range`, and the function needs to iterate over each row.
- Iterate through the groupby object

  - [Iterating through groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)
- The function `def get_future_sum` makes a calculation for every row of the grouped dataframe, and returns a sum.
- Save the result of each group in a `list`
- Use `pd.concat` to create a single dataframe from the list of dataframes
- The expected output shown in the question is not correct, for the given data.

  - *For example, for `id=1`, there is no data for next 6 months so, sum will be `0`*
  - *For `id=2`, there is 1 num in next 6 months, so `total=1`*
- Also see [Group by: split-apply-combine user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# test data and dataframe
data = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'date': [pd.Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2006-01-05 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2005-04-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00')],
        'num': [7, 2, 1, 1, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# updated function
def get_future_sum(val: pd.Series, d: pd.DataFrame) -> np.int64:
    end_date = val.date + relativedelta(months=+6)
    date_range = d[(d['date'] > val.date) & (d['date'] <= end_date)]
    return date_range['num'].sum()


dfg = list()
for g, dg in df.groupby('id'):
    dg['total'] = dg.apply(lambda x: get_future_sum(x, dg), axis=1)
    dfg.append(dg)

# create new dataframe from list of dataframes
df_total = pd.concat(dfg).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df_total)
   id       date  num  total
0   1 2005-01-01    7      0
1   1 2006-01-05    2      0
2   2 2005-01-01    1      1
3   2 2005-04-01    1      0
4   3 2009-01-01    2      0
```